# shared objects in background worker in Adobe air app

Tags: air, adobe, backgroundworker, local-shared-object

I am working with adobe air-app. I created a background worker. and in that worker if I create a new local shared object or want to get attach to my local shared object. It creates a new shared object but I am unable to get its physical location.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look on stackoverflow or google about it. Since you do not required something else special I hope the following links can help

[how to validate the radio button group? in flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460000/how-to-validate-the-radio-button-group-in-flex)

http://captaincode.wordpress.com/2009/10/29/validating-a-checkbox-in-flex-via-mxml/